# How to add (and connect) a new sub-module into an existing compound module using NED inheritance

Tags: omnet++

I have a compound module that has several sub-modules that are connected to each other and to the parent compound module's gates. I want to create a new compound module type that is exactly like this one except I want to insert and additional sub-module between two sub-modules that were  already connected. Or stated differently: I want to replace a connection in the original type with a sub-module in the new type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I've figured out: This is possible with OMNeT++ 5.6 or later using the `@reconnect` property on the newly defined connection in the sub-type. That property switches off the checking that an existing connection cannot be redefined. Instead, it properly removes the original connection and allows adding a new one in the sub-type.

```html
module twoActionModule {
    gates:
        input i;
        output o;
    submodules:
        actionA: ActionA;
        actionC: ActionC;
    connections:
        i --> actionA.i;
        actionA.o --> actionC.i;
        actionC.o --> o;
}

module threeActionModule extends twoActionModule {
    submodules:
        actionB: ActionB;
    connections:
        actionA.o --> { @reconnect; } --> actionB.i; // breaks the connection between A and C
        actionB.o --> actionC.i;
}
```